Calculate the percentage of video watching progress and save it
I am developing an Android application using Kotlin with Android Studio. I want to display the video playback progress in a ProgressBar and a TextView while the user watches a video with ExoPlayer.
However, I want to ensure that if the user skips or rewinds the video using the SeekBar, those skipped or repeated sections are not included in the calculation of the progress percentage. I only want the progress percentage to reflect the time the video is actually played, moment by moment.
Additionally, I want each second that is viewed to be counted only once towards the progress percentage, so if the user rewatches certain sections of the video, those repeated seconds are not counted again in the progress calculation.
I also need to save this progress percentage, the viewed seconds, and the related video details, so that when the app is closed and reopened, the information for each video is preserved. When a video is played again, the progress calculation should continue from where it left off based on the previously saved data.
Moreover, I want the user to be able to resume watching the video from where they left off when re-entering the activity. It should be clear where the user last watched before exiting the activity.
Please help me implement this functionality in my code. Also, if I need to add any libraries for this, please let me know.
Thank you in advance for your help.
class ViewWatchLessonsActivity(
    private val context: Context
) {

    val binding = ActivityWatchLessonsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))

    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
    private val textViewProgress = binding.txtProgressNumber
    private val progressBar = binding.progressBar

    private var videoDuration: Long = 0
    private var totalPlaybackTime: Long = 0
    private var isUserSeeking: Boolean = false
    private var progress: Int = 0
    private val visitedSeconds = mutableSetOf<Int>()


    fun initVideoView(videoAddress: Int) {

        binding.playerViewOfLessons.player = player

        val mediaItem =
            MediaItem.fromUri("android.resource://${context.packageName}/${videoAddress}")
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        player.prepare()

        player.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: Int) {
                when (state) {
                    Player.STATE_READY -> {
                        videoDuration = player.duration
                        updateProgressBar()
                    }
                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> {
                        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
                    }
                }
            }

            @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
            override fun onPositionDiscontinuity(reason: Int) {
                if (reason == Player.DISCONTINUITY_REASON_SEEK) {
                    isUserSeeking = false
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun updateProgressBar() {
        handler.post(object : Runnable {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            override fun run() {
                val currentPosition = player.currentPosition

                if (!isUserSeeking) {
                    val currentSecond = (currentPosition / 1000).toInt()

                    if (!visitedSeconds.contains(currentSecond)) {
                        visitedSeconds.add(currentSecond)
                        totalPlaybackTime += 1000
                    }

                    progress = (totalPlaybackTime / videoDuration.toFloat() * 100).toInt()
                    textViewProgress.text = "$progress/100%"
                    progressBar.progress = progress
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
            }
        })
    }

    fun onPause() {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        player.pause()
    }


    fun onResume() {
        updateProgressBar()
    }


    fun onDestroy() {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        player.release()
    }

}

"I have tested this code. It calculates the video progress percentage the way I want (i.e., user manipulation of the SeekBar doesn't affect it, and repeated seconds are not counted). However, my problem is that no matter what I tried, I couldn't store the progress percentage in such a way that upon re-entering the activity, the progress percentage would be calculated based on the previous information, and the video playback would resume from where it left off. Instead, when re-entering the activity, the progress percentage is shown as zero in both the TextView and the ProgressBar."
"By the way, I tested this method with both SharedPreferences and the room database, but in both methods, I encountered this problem when saving."

"I have tested this code. It calculates the video progress percentage the way I want" Great! But the code that isn't working would be more relevant in the question. Using SharedPrefefences would be one way. How have you tried that? Did you remember to commit() or apply() the changes to SharedPreferences? You can edit the question and add or replace some code.

yes
I used apply() where necessary. But despite this, the progress percentage is displayed as zero when re-entering the activity. Have you tried the save operation with this code???

"Have you tried the save operation with this code???" The code in the question has no save operation trying to save anything to SharedPreferences or a read operation trying to read anything from there. But yes, I've used SharedPreferences for storing some data. Your question is still showing the code that already works and not the code that doesn't work, so people can't tell you what is wrong.

I removed the codes related to SharedPreferences from the code before posting it here. Because with them, not only was the storage operation not working correctly, but the same codes also became problematic and didn’t function properly anymore.
If anyone can add the SharedPreferences code in a way that achieves the intended goal, please do so, and I would appreciate it if you could share it here with others.

You can save the last video position in SharedPreference and can set it when the video player is ready by using seekTo method. Im sharing the code it will help you
    val preference: SharedPreferences =
        activity.getSharedPreferences(application.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    
    fun getLastVideoPosition(): Long {
        return preference.getLong(ConstantsUtil.VIDEO_LAST_PLAYED_POSITION, 0L)
    }

    fun saveLastVideoPosition(videoPosition: Long) {
        preference.edit().putLong(ConstantsUtil.VIDEO_LAST_PLAYED_POSITION, videoPosition)
            .apply()
    }

    player?.seekTo(preference.getLastVideoPosition())

you can add seekTo method after player.prepare() line in initVideoView function.
Your updated methods
fun initVideoView(videoAddress: Int) {

    binding.playerViewOfLessons.player = player

    val mediaItem =
        MediaItem.fromUri("android.resource://${context.packageName}/${videoAddress}")
    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
    player.prepare()
    player.seekTo(preference.getLastVideoPosition()) //Update here

    player.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
        override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: Int) {
            when (state) {
                Player.STATE_READY -> {
                    videoDuration = player.duration
                    updateProgressBar()
                }
                Player.STATE_ENDED -> {
                    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
                }
            }
        }

        @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
        override fun onPositionDiscontinuity(reason: Int) {
            if (reason == Player.DISCONTINUITY_REASON_SEEK) {
                isUserSeeking = false
            }
        }
    })
}

 private fun updateProgressBar() {
    handler.post(object : Runnable {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun run() {
            val currentPosition = player.currentPosition

            if (!isUserSeeking) {
                val currentSecond = (currentPosition / 1000).toInt()
                saveLastVideoPosition(currentPosition) //Update here

                if (!visitedSeconds.contains(currentSecond)) {
                    visitedSeconds.add(currentSecond)
                    totalPlaybackTime += 1000
                }

                progress = (totalPlaybackTime / videoDuration.toFloat() * 100).toInt()
                textViewProgress.text = "$progress/100%"
                progressBar.progress = progress
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }
    })
}

